# Laurent Expansion of $\frac{(z+1)^2}{z(z^3+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I’m stuck on finding the Laurent expansion this function about $z=0$:

$$\frac{(z+1)^2}{z(z^3+1)}$$

What I tried was to compute the Binomial Expansion for the top bit and then expand:

$$\frac{1}{1+z^3}=\frac{1}{z^3}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{z^3})}$$

I ended up with the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}2\\n\end{pmatrix}z^{n-4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nz^{4-3n}$$

Now I don’t know if I’m right what I have and if I am how can I continue. I don’t know if I’m allowed to do a Cauchy Product here.

Many thanks !

Comment: $z$ is small, so you don't want to manipulate $\frac{1}{1+z^3}$ like that.

Comment: @J.G. Oh yeah you are right, but what about the rest?

Comment: The maximum $n$ with $\binom{2}{n}\ne0$ is $n=2$. It's easiest to start from $\frac1z(1+2z+z^2)(1-z^3+z^6-\cdots)$.

Comment: Ok it makes perfect sense now, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\frac{(z+1)^2}{z(z^3+1)} 
   &=&\displaystyle
   \left(z+2+\frac{1}{z}\right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^{3k} \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^{3k+1} + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^{3k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^{3k-1}  \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(2z^{3k}+z^{3k+1}-z^{3k+2}\right)
\end{array}
$$
where the first term of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{3k-1}$ (corresponding to $k=0$) has been extracted from the sum, before re-indexing it.

Comment: Not quite: the last factor should give $z^{3k}$ a $(-1)^k$ coefficient.

Comment: How? I found the second term so the sum just with $z^{3k-1}$ at the end

Comment: They were typos, now edited.

Comment: All good now thanks you !